# Array of 4Kb? MemTable & SSTable

Tags: java, arrays, caching, memory

How can I create an array of String which can contain only 4Kb of data, if my input is like "key0000000090201value00000090201", where key0000000090201 is the key & value00000090201 is the value.

I have a input which has entries like *"put,key0000000090201,,value00000090201"*

I'm creating in-memory buffer, which can be an array to collect recently admitted KV items. This buffer is named Memtable. When my Memtable gets filled up I have to write to disk as SSTable.

Comment: Please explain exactly where you're stuck. Read [ask].

Comment: Basically I don't know how to create an array of Strings which can only have 4KB of items. 
Is there any way we can create an array of String which can only contain 4Kb of Items?

Comment: No, you'll need to keep track of the size of the collection as you add strings to it.